# Why some spatial functions does not exists on my mysql server?

Tags: mysql, spatial

I have installed a new local MySQL server (Version8) for a dev usage.
I want to use spatial functions, but some of them does not exists.

This script returns me a good value:

```sql
create database test;
use test;
select st_x(point(15, 20));
```

> 15

So, I though spatial extension was natively installed, but as soon as I use other functions like `geomfromtext`, my script throws an error:

```
create database test;
use test;
SELECT geomfromtext('Point(15 20)');
```

> Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION test.geomfromtext does not exist    0.000 sec

I don't understand, the autocompletion of MySQL Workbench console completes geometry.
[image: Autocompletion]

Which step did I forget during installation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just flew over the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html) and it seems that the function is called [ST_GeomFromText()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html#function_st-geomfromtext) in MySQL 8.0.

> In MySQL 5.7, several spatial functions available under multiple names
>   were deprecated to move in the direction of making the spatial
>   function namespace more consistent, the goal being that each spatial
>   function name begin with ST_ if it performs an exact operation, or
>   with MBR if it performs an operation based on minimum bounding
>   rectangles. In MySQL 8.0, the deprecated functions are removed to
>   leave only the corresponding ST_ and MBR functions:
>
> - These functions are removed in favor of the MBR names: Contains(), Disjoint(), Equals(), Intersects(), Overlaps(), Within().
> - These functions are removed in favor of the ST_ names: Area(), AsBinary(), AsText(), AsWKB(), AsWKT(), Buffer(), Centroid(),
>     ConvexHull(), Crosses(), Dimension(), Distance(), EndPoint(),
>     Envelope(), ExteriorRing(), GeomCollFromText(), GeomCollFromWKB(),
>     GeomFromText(), GeomFromWKB(), GeometryCollectionFromText(),
>     GeometryCollectionFromWKB(), GeometryFromText(), GeometryFromWKB(),
>     GeometryN(), GeometryType(), InteriorRingN(), IsClosed(), IsEmpty(),
>     IsSimple(), LineFromText(), LineFromWKB(), LineStringFromText(),
>     LineStringFromWKB(), MLineFromText(), MLineFromWKB(),
>     MPointFromText(), MPointFromWKB(), MPolyFromText(), MPolyFromWKB(),
>     MultiLineStringFromText(), MultiLineStringFromWKB(),
>     MultiPointFromText(), MultiPointFromWKB(), MultiPolygonFromText(),
>     MultiPolygonFromWKB(), NumGeometries(), NumInteriorRings(),
>     NumPoints(), PointFromText(), PointFromWKB(), PointN(),
>     PolyFromText(), PolyFromWKB(), PolygonFromText(), PolygonFromWKB(),
>     SRID(), StartPoint(), Touches(), X(), Y().
> - GLength() is removed in favor of ST_Length().

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot! It seems that a lot of functions was deprecated in MySQL5 and disappears in 8.0.